# How can I calculate modulo of a large number in String format in java

Tags: java, math, biginteger, bigdecimal, exponent

I am trying to calculate an expression in java which is in String 
i.e
`99999999999999999^99999999999999999`
I want to calculate this number modulo `1000000007`.
I currently trying to store the big numbers as double but taking modulo with double gives me `NaN`.
Can somebody help ?

Comment: `99999999999999999^99999999999999999` is a rather ... large number. You're going to have to apply maths rather than brute force.

Comment: Can't we use double here ?

Comment: Define 'I tried' and 'didn't work'.

Comment: Do you realize what is the actual value of `99999999999999999^99999999999999999`? You cannot even compute that number in reasonable time. Let alone do any calculation with it.

Comment: Just removed the tried part. :)

Comment: We can't help you with what you tried and didn't work unless you post it.

Comment: OK, I got my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can somebody remove that downvote ?

Comment: @piyush121 if you interested to know behind mathematics of Big modulo, you can check this [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/get-the-modulo-of-a-very-large-number-that-cannot-be-stored-in-any-data-type-in-cc-1/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `BigInteger` and [`modPow(BigInteger, BigInteger)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-) like

```
BigInteger m = new BigInteger("1000000007");
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("99999999999999999");
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("99999999999999999");
BigInteger answer = a.modPow(b, m);
System.out.println(answer);
```

which gives

```
265859324
```

Comment: That's the one.